# Change Checkbox value without raising event

Tags: c#

I want to change Checkbox value without raising the onCheck event.
I know there are work arounds like un registering ,changing the value then re- registering,
Inside the event method based on flag either skip or evaluating the method statements
or any other work arounds.
I am looking for a cleaner ways for it.

Comment: Is this winforms or webforms? The answer is considerably different in each case.

Comment: If you need that functionality, you probably have a ugly design in head, or creating a harder solution than needed... Tell us why you want to do that and perhaps you won't need an answer anymore.

Comment: Dear Stormenet,
The thing is i want to perform certain validation when checkbox is checked.
after the user decides not to proceede,the value has to be reset.

Comment: It is for a windows based application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can derive from CheckBox class, override [CheckBox.OnCheckedChanged Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.oncheckedchanged.aspx)  and do not call the base class's OnCheckedChanged method and the event will not be fired. You can also have a property which indicates whether the event should be raised or not.

Comment: Well cant do that,
As the codebase has already used many checkboxes.changing them will be a herculean task.
This i had thought of when i encountered the problem.but not feasible

Comment: this sounds reasonable and works both for Web forms and for Win forms

Comment: @Ravisha, why? It's just string replacement in all files!

Comment: i agree it is just string replacement.but are you concluding that with the provided Checkbox its impossible?

Comment: Do you need that functionality in all checkboxes you use in the whole codebase? If you only need in in one place you can use the derived version.

Comment: Well i require it in many places.Thats the reason i am looking for a cleaner way

Comment: Although it's old question but this will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595063/how-to-set-checkbox-icchecked-without-raising-event

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old thread but the answer given is way too much trouble.
I almost never use the OnCheckedChanged event.  I prefer to use OnMouseUp instead.  That way you can set check boxes or radio buttons like you want them on startup without triggering the events.

In the OnMouseUp event check to see if the box is checked after the mouseUp happens like this..

```
private void chkBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   if (chkBox1.Checked)
   {
      // do some stuff if the box is checked after a mouseup on it
   }   
}
```

I've been doing it this way for a long time.  It use to be a big hassle to put flag variables in OnChanged Events to tell functions not to do anything while we are setting the box states.  Using MouseUp is way easier.
gc

Comment: Do you also add an `OnKeyUp` handler for when users toggle the checked state using the spacebar?

Answer (score 3):

Remove and Reassign handler:

```
myCheckbox.Checked -= myCheckbox_Checked;
myCheckbox.IsChecked = true;
myCheckbox.Checked += myCheckbox_Checked;
```