# How to set checkbox.isChecked without raising event

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

Is there a way of checking the `CheckBox` without running the code associated to checking it? Just for visual appearance.

Edit:

```
private void normalCheck_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    normal();
}
```

Imagine that I want to set the `normalCheckBox.IsChecked=true;` but without raising the event. Is that possible?

Comment: He wants to programmatically set the "Checked" property of a checkbox without it raising the Checked event, even though he has subscribed to the Checked event.

Comment: Wow @MatthewWatson you are a mind reader ;)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

One way would be to detach the event handler, set the `IsChecked` property, and then reattach it.

```
myCheckbox.Checked -= myCheckbox_Checked;
myCheckbox.IsChecked = true;
myCheckbox.Checked += myCheckbox_Checked;
```

Comment: What's with the minus and plus? I don't get it. Looks very interesting tho.

Comment: @iMohammad - The `-` will detach the event handler from the `myCheckbox` control. So any code that would normally fire after the `Checked` event won't be called (because you've removed the event handler). The `+` simply attaches the event handler back so that, from now on, if the `Checked` event is fired then the event handler code is also called.

Comment: I believe you can abbreviate it to `myCheckbox.Checked -= myCheckbox_Checked;` (and the other similarly).

Comment: I had to make the modification on the left side for both "-=" and "+=" lines:

`myCheckbox.CheckChanged -= myCheckbox_Changed;`

(CheckChanged rather than Checked)

Comment: @iluomo - just to clarify, `Checked` is for the WPF framework. I assume you're using WinForms which is why you need to use `CheckChanged` instead

Answer (score 19):

You could use the `Click` event instead of `Checked` and use the state of the checkbox like below:

```
private void normalCheck_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (normalCheck.IsChecked ?? false) { normal(); }
}
```

Then, this event won't be raised by using `normalCheck.IsChecked = true;`. It will only be raised by a click.

NOTE: The null-coalescing operator (`??`) is necessary because `IsChecked` returns a `bool?` type which could be null.

Comment: much saver, in my opinion, than Checked/Unchecked events

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - avoids race conditions and more predictable.

Answer (score 1):

For Unchecked Event : ( based on the solution of @keyboardP )

```
myCheckbox.Unchecked -= myCheckbox_Unchecked;
myCheckbox.IsChecked = false;
myCheckbox.Unchecked += myCheckbox_Unchecked;
```

Comment: Is this answer providing anything new?

Comment: Maybe for you it provide anything new

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to changing the checked status without raising the "_Checked" event, you will likely have to override the event handler with a param to tell it to skip the event or not.

Related answer: [Change Checkbox value without raising event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108762/change-checkbox-value-without-raising-event)